# Make Wordpress Read MD5 Encryption

Tags: php, wordpress, md5

I Have a Wordpress website which I recently developed.
My old site had about 4000 users and I've got all their data with passwords encrypted using MD5

I'm using a plugin named Import Users From CSV to Import my users to the new site.

However, The encrypted passwords are being read as Plain Text.

I'm confused! I thought Wordpress supports MD5 encryption.

Is there any way to make it read all those passwords?

Comment: MD5 is not a encryption. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Your thought wrong, wp uses phpass which if did use md5 it would of been heavily salted and not a standard hash. There is no way to convert it to the new bcrypt method unless you got the passwords in plaintext.

Comment: You could though implement something like a remote logging check into the old site though an out-of-band curl call, if its success write the inputted password to the users account, this would then be transparent to the user.

Comment: You can use these MD5 hashes by developping your own plugin. to know how to create plugin look here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin then, if you have questions, there is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you thought of doing this through your MYSQL directly?

Comment: WordPress generally does support MD5-encoded passwords as a legacy feature. They're rewritten to phpass once the user successfully logs in. If it's not working for you, there's something else funky going on.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone. WordPress does support MD5 passwords. I've used this a few times to reset forgotten passwords on servers which cannot send emails.